# Matlab Function - ask for user input for given argument

Tags: matlab, function, input, name-value, basicnamevaluepair

I have a Matlab `function` that has numerous name-value parameter inputs. For some of the parameter names, there are a lot of possible values (which are not always obvious) that the user can choose from. What I would like to do is, **IF** the user calls the name, but does NOT give a value, **THEN** Matlab would display possible entries **AND THEN** take the user's input.

For example I have a function such as:

```
function getSomeData( varargin )

p=inputParser;
defaultData='abc';

addParameter(p, 'Data', defaultData);

parse(p,varargin{:});

end
```

If the user were to call the function in the command window such as:

```
>> getSomeData('Data')
```

in which the user did not give a value for `'Data'`, the window would display and prompt

```
>> getSomeData('Data')
No value for 'Data' Given
Possible Values of 'Data' are:
'abc'
'def'
'other'

Please input your 'Data':
```

in which I could use the `result=input(prompt)` function.

Any help or advice is very much appreciated! Cheers

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your code.  So you say you have a function already available that takes in name-value pairs?  How are these name-values obtained to begin with?  Your `getSomeData` function seems to just set up some default data, then goes through a function called `parse`.  What does `parse` do?  Can you show us **all** of your code?

Answer (score 0):

May I ask you to specify the complexity of your input stuff. Either you come from java and think that you need to create an I/O object to be able to read inputs, or else your problem is more complex that the description gives the impression of.

Otherwise, I would give you the design of a less complicated way forward here. One way to do this is to use the `nargin` property, which finds the number of inputs to the function. Together with `nargin`, use an if statement (or switch-case?).

```
if nargin==0
    % print alternative inputs with disp or fprintf.
    % This alternative can also be replaced with comments (single block with
    % no empty rows) right below the function. This will then be seen with
    % the `help funName` command

elseif nargin==1
    % Print description + permitted values. This can be done from a
    % switch-case statement (if you want the switch-case statement
    % can be placed in an external function).

elseif ~mod(nargin,2)
    %parse input pairs and do the calculations.

else
    error('wrong number of input arguments');
    % or
    % fprintf('wrong number of input arguments\n');
    % set outputs to '', {}, [], ...
    % return;
end
```

I hope this helps even though it is not exactly the solution proposed by you. This is however a simple solution with the advantage that you do not mix up the information parts and execution parts. My guess is that this is a convenient way to work with I/O without implementing a complicated parser.

These problems are otherwise normally solved by a complicated parser with a lot of different commands (compare with the terminal (unix based) of cmd prompt (windows)).